In what generality should a question be asked?
Let's say I'm working on a problem $P$. I ultimately want to solve $P$ myself, but of course I am open to help from others. Let's say I know (or suspect) that an affirmative answer to a much simpler conjecture $c$ will imply the answer, and let's say I suspect conjecture $c$ to be true. However, an unaffirmative answer to conjecture $c$ will be enlightening, but ultimately have me asking more questions.
In real life, I would 100% ask my peers their opinion on conjecture $c$, since

It is much simpler, and my peers (who presumably know less about problem $P$ than me) would much more likely be able to answer conjecture $c$.
If the answer is not in the affirmative, I can immediately ask a slightly weaker version $c'$ who's answer is also enlightening from the perspective of tackling problem $P$, and if $c'$ also turns out to be false I can ask $c''$ etc.
It ultimately would feel like I did "the majority" of the work.

However, on SE point number 2 presents a huge problem, since in the case $c$ is false, it would be unfair for me to go "great, what about $c'$? How about $c''$? etc."
In this situation, what would the advice be? Should I just ask $P$?

You can ask questions both about C on its own and about P predicated on C being affirmed. If the question about C was a rejection of its truth, you can ask a question about what appropriate changes X are necessary to make C+X true. Those would all be good ideas for questions.

You are allowed to ask multiple questions.  It is perfectly fine to post a question asking if $c$ is true.  Then if you get an answer proving $c$ is not true, then you can post a new question asking if $c'$ is true.  Meanwhile, you can also post a question asking whether $P$ is true.
If you do this, of course make sure to include appropriate context: motivation for asking the question, progress you have made, etc.
The thing that is not ok is to post a question asking whether $c$ is true, then if you get an answer proving that $c$ is not true, changing that question to ask about $c'$.  That's not OK, because it would invalidate the existing answer.  It's also not OK to leave a comment asking "ok, what about $c'$?", because that is not the purpose of comments.  But it is OK to post a new question.
Make sure that the questions you post are well-motivated, and that you describe the motivation.  If you post a large number of conjectures, asking if each is true, the community might not appreciate that and might downvote your questions.  This site is not intended to help you -- or, rather, it's not here just to help you.  It is intended to provide a place where people can come together and collaborate to build an archive/library of knowledge that will be useful to others.  So if you are asking a question that will be useful to others, great!  If you are asking a question that it's unlikely anyone else will ever have, then some members of the community might not be so enthusiastic about that, and the reception to such questions might vary.

Thank you! I am guilty of the thing that is not ok, but I now know what to do. Highly appreciate your answer.

@Calculus101, no worries, thank you for asking and being open to learning about the norms and expectations on this site!  I think that is very positive.

One small addendum to D.W.'s answer:  it sounds like you are trying to use Math SE as a resource for your own research.  As a general rule[1], questions on Math SE should focus on (relatively) well-trod mathematics.  This is not a research site, nor is it a social network for mathematical collaboration.  If you are working on a research problem, it is possible that MathOverflow might (possibly) be a more appropriate place to ask.

[1] To preempt the pedants:  note that I have used the phrase "as a general rule".  This is not an absolute, but it is reflective of the general philosophy of Math SE.

Oh the $P$ may not necessarily be a research problem, it could be an exercise I'm working on, and when I say "conjecture" I really just mean a statement I think is probably true (but could well be well-known).
